# Is a line break required between comments and PHP open/close tags?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I'm currently migrating several websites from SiteGround to AWS.  For the sites now on AWS, I'm noticing instances where PHP comments are outputting on the page.

I've been racking my brain to figure out why they output on AWS but not SiteGround, and I just noticed that this comment outputs on the page:

```
<?php/*
<div class="form_labelTop1">
  <div class="form_labelTop1_label"></div>
  <input type="text" class="readOnly_calculated" value=<?php echo '"'.$_SESSION["user_var"]["browser_prefix"].'"'; ?> readonly>
</div>
*/?>
```

...but when I add line breaks, it disappears from the page:

```
<?php
/*
<div class="form_labelTop1">
  <div class="form_labelTop1_label"></div>
  <input type="text" class="readOnly_calculated" value=<?php echo '"'.$_SESSION["user_var"]["browser_prefix"].'"'; ?> readonly>
</div>
*/
?>
```

I'm wondering if I've been doing this wrong the whole time (i.e. yes, comments should have line breaks) but SiteGround simply wasn't as picky?  Or is there another issue at play?

PHP versions are slightly different in each environment, which I suppose could be a factor.  But honestly I have no clue:

- PHP 7.1.28 (AWS)
- PHP 7.1.30 (SiteGround)

Comment: No, but at least a space. `/*` is intended for multiline comments. `//` or `#` for single lines.

Comment: Looks like v5.4 is the only version that allows no whitespace at all between the open tag and the open comment. See [here](https://3v4l.org/nKdrW) versus [here](https://3v4l.org/UhcDA). But even then, it throws a notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Alex and Markus for this information!

I just tested a single space between open/close tags and this does seem to work as well.  I thought I tested this before posting but apparently not.

Still strange that this was a non-issue on SiteGround, but good to know there's a reason for this newfound chaos.